# Clamped B-spline: repeat knots or control points

Tags: spline

When we want a B-spline that reaches its first and last control points (clamped B-spline or open uniform B-spline), we can play on the multiplicity of the first and last knot of the knot vector $u = (u_0,...,u_{m})$ for a B-spline of order $k$ (degree $p$, $p = k-1$) with $m = n+k$ control points.

To get a clamped B-spline, we can use the following constraint :

$u_0 = u_1 = \cdots = u_p \text{ and } u_{m-p} = u_{m-p+1} = \cdots = u_m$.

[image: open uniform B-spline]

However, we can also "duplicate" the first and last control points to achieve this. So what are the exact differences between these two methods? (continuity, etc.)

Here is a visual comparison of the two methods: **control point multiplicity** in green, **knot multiplicity** in red.

[image: Visual comparison]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating knots is the usual approach. If you repeat control vertices, you'll get a curve that has zero derivative vectors of several orders at the end-points, which will cause problems. It will make it difficult to calculate tangent vectors, normal vectors, curvature, torsion, and so on, for example. Even having a zero first derivative is bad news.