# Matrix Representation for Clamped b-spline

Tags: geometry, curves, spline

I wanted to know how can I write a matrix representation of a clamped b-spline. Following this document, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/731996, I get matrix representation to write b-spline matrices(unclamped). I am able to generate clamped version from that by repeating the control points though that looks different if I generate from a library(scipy.interpolate.splev) - and I think the difference stems from that it considers the multiplicity of knot vector rather than control points. I am not able to get that formulation with respect to the paper mentioned above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: By taking two or three points very close  to the clamped end,  accuracy of B- Spline/Bezier may perhaps suffice.

Comment: That may do for accuracy. But I am looking to clamp by repeating knot vector. This is because with repeating control points, the derivates come out to be zero at endpoints which I don't want. This is similar to what the answer of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398123/clamped-b-spline-repeat-knots-or-control-points says. So, I am trying to get non-zero endpoint derivatives.

Comment: Should the normal to the curve lie along line joining first and last points?